# Jenkins XCode iOS build failure due to missing module maps

Tags: xcode, jenkins, cocoapods, xcode12, fbsdk

I have a project with integrated Facebook SDK and I'm trying to build the project using my Jenkins xCode Integration, since I'm using CocoaPods I have to build the project using xcworkspace instead of xcproj file.
If I open the workspace manually, archive and export ipa, everything works great.
If I try to run the exact same process through Jenkins I'm getting an error on one of my pods stating that FBSDKcoreKite module.map can't be found, and that the Swiftshims module is missing.
(as far as I know the swiftshims is part of the xCode and should only show missing if the path to it is somehow corrupt in the caching of xCode.
I've tried cleaning my build, my build folder, removing derived data, erasing the xcodemodule folder, reinstalling pods, setup pods, and basically anything I could find online).

Any ideas as to what I can do to fix this?
(using xCode12).
Attaching exact build snippet:

> CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/Swift/Enums+Extensions.swift
> cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -emit-bc /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/Swift/Enums+Extensions.swift -emit-module-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FBSDKShareKit.swiftmodule -emit-module-doc-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FBSDKShareKit.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FBSDKShareKit.swiftsourceinfo -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Enums+Extensions.dia -emit-objc-header-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FBSDKShareKit-Swift.h -emit-dependencies-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Enums+Extensions.d -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.1.sdk -I /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/build -I /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit -F /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/build -g -import-underlying-module -module-cache-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -O -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.modulemap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/build/include -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Private -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Private/FBSDKShareKit -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -target-sdk-version 14.1 -parse-as-library -module-name FBSDKShareKit -num-threads 4 -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Enums+Extensions.bc
> **:0: error: module map file '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap' not found
> :0: error: module map file '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap' not found
> :0: error: missing required module 'SwiftShims'**

> CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
> cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods
> export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
> export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.1.sdk
> >/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name FBSDKShareKit -O -whole-module-optimization -enforce-exclusivity=checked -D COCOAPODS -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap -import-underlying-module -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.modulemap -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.1.sdk -target armv7-apple-ios9.0 -g -module-cache-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -embed-bitcode -swift-version 5 -I /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/build -I /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit -F /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/build -parse-as-library -c -num-threads 4 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/Swift/Enums+Extensions.swift -output-file-map /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBSDKShareKit-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBSDKShareKit.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/build/include -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Private -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Private/FBSDKShareKit -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/DerivedSources-normal/armv7 -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBSDKShareKit-Swift.h -working-directory /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods

> CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/Swift/Enums+Extensions.swift
> cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -emit-bc /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/Swift/Enums+Extensions.swift -emit-module-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBSDKShareKit.swiftmodule -emit-module-doc-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBSDKShareKit.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBSDKShareKit.swiftsourceinfo -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Enums+Extensions.dia -emit-objc-header-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBSDKShareKit-Swift.h -emit-dependencies-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Enums+Extensions.d -target armv7-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.1.sdk -I /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/build -I /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit -F /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/build -g -import-underlying-module -module-cache-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -O -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.modulemap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/FBSDKShareKit-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/build/include -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Private -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Private/FBSDKShareKit -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/Headers/Public/FBSDKShareKit -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/DerivedSources-normal/armv7 -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -target-sdk-version 14.1 -parse-as-library -module-name FBSDKShareKit -num-threads 4 -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cahmainqljispgcpsolojgyjxcxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Enums+Extensions.bc

** BUILD FAILED **

> The following build commands failed:
> **CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
> CompileSwift normal arm64
> CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
> CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/SlotsNetwork-iOS/trunk/slots-network/iOSBuild-bonanzaparty/Pods/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/Swift/Enums+Extensions.swift
> (4 failures)**
> Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after several days I finally figured what was the issue in my case,
The Jenkins deployment has a special "build path" configuration, the new XCode I installed was using a different build path for it's build path (a folder with a hash name xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-build) - since FBSDKShareKit uses FBSDKCoreKit import for the compilation of Swift components, it looks at the **Jenkin's build path** for the FBSDKCoreKit instead of the temp build folder the xCode creates for it.
So in order to fix the process all I did was remove the Build path configuration from the Jenkins xCode Integration plugin and now everything works perfectly.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You said you deleted derived data and pod update so i passed these stages so :

try
Delete your pod file and create a new one and be sure that

```
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

go to command line as usual and install your pods again

```
pod install
```

---

If it is not work
try this one

go to **Build Settings** and search **Framework Search Paths**

```
Replace the ~/Documents/FacebookSDK to $(HOME)/Documents/FacebookSDK (with parentheses)
```

---

If it is not work also.
Be sure that

`FBSDKShareKit` in your **Copy Bundle Resources** other Facebook kits as well.

[image]